# Difference between NoAutoUpdate key and NoWindowsUpdate Registry keys to disable updates

Tags: windows-update, registrykey

What is the difference between two registry keys NoWindowsUpdate and NoAutoUpdate? Is there a difference in location also?
I don't want the windows update to not get downloaded also but when I used NoWindowUpdate set to 1 the updates were getting downloaded.(could be the ones pushed by the IT team)
so what can I use ?